# Error in rowSums(x) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions (Vegan:oecosimu)

Tags: arrays, r, bipartite, vegan

I am trying to use the application oecosimu in Vegan package.

```
library(sna)
 library(permute)
library(lattice)
library(vegan)
library(bipartite)
bio<-read.csv("/home/vicar66/Raw_data/Jan12/98percents_April_16/otu_table/Chapter1/no_bloom_bio_data_L3.txt")
rownames(bio)<-bio[,1]
bio[,1]<-NULL
bio_m<-as.matrix(bio)
a<-oecosimu(bio_m,bipartite::C.score,"swap")
```

but I keep having this error message:
Attaching package: 'bipartite'

The following object is masked from 'package:vegan':

```
nullmodel
```

Error in rowSums(x) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
Calls: oecosimu -> nullmodel -> rowSums
Execution halted

demo data:

```
    Ciliophora  Dinoflagellates MALVs   Choanoflagellida
DNAHIN5m    0.062469804 0.826323018 0.031084701 0.000323747
DNAHIN35m   0.045216826 0.595750636 0.187010719 0.000917053
DNAHIN150m  0.018434224 0.204865296 0.531016032 0.017009618
DNAHIN240m  0.016211333 0.889640227 0.04191846  0.03087407
```

**first column first row is empty. First row are rownames

Anyone have encountered this problem yet?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I use vegan quite frequently but not specifically this application. Could you provide some (demo) data? I would like to see if I have the same issue on my machine and if it could be solved...

Comment: have you tried loading vegan after bipartite yet?

Comment: I tried loading vegan before. I just added demo to the original post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your demo data in this format it is a bit difficult to get it into R. Try posting the output of dput(objectwithdemodata) here.

Comment: I am not sure how to add my data as an object. Is it possible to send them by pm? Sorry I am new to this website!

Comment: normally dput(bio_m) should work but if you prefer a pm that's fine with me too.

Comment: Do you get the error with the demo data you provided? I haven't tried that data yet, but I can't reproduce this with the data built into vegan using `C.score` and `"swap"` as options. I would check closely that the data are OK using `str(bio)` and check all is well.

Comment: Looks very much like a problem with your data (`bio_m`): I tried the same example with `sipoo` data in **vegan**, and it worked OK.

Comment: A simple test is to try `bipartite::C.score(bio_m)`: does this work? If it fails, check `bio_m`.

Comment: Hi thanks for all comments, sorry i was on vacation. So i tried using the demo I get the same error. I tried the bipartite::C.score(bio_m) but my only output is [1] NaN.

Comment: And FM Kerckhof, I try to find a way to send you by pm, but i can't find option for pm on the website. do you have the link to the page I should find the pm box? Thanks!

Comment: I managed to resolve it! Actually i was using relative abundance but then I tried with subsampled OTUs and it worked. Thanks everyone for your help!